# How to remove whites space on mobile device using css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have banner which have image , unfortunately when I try responsiveness at certain break point I get white space ,

Here is the website am doing : [Problem with white space](http://marketingbiznes-dev.webcrafters.pl/)

[image]

I tried

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

what do I need  to do to get rid of the white space on my page its annoying, please help ;(

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to find it. But I think I did.

```
.marketing-main-page-content_description-right p {
     width: 600px;
}
```

On line 305 style.css. 
Remowe this rule or write media query.

Answer (score 0):

In "marketing-main-page-content-agenda_elipse" container you have 2 elements that have absolute positions "elipse-top" & "elipse-bottom" they give the container extra width based on their "right" position, try to change their properties in responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `%` unit in `body` and `html` tags. Instead, using `vw` unit, which stands for **viewport width**. `1vw` equal to 1% of viewport width. That means you need `100vw` for `html, body`.

```
html, body {
    width: 100vw
}
```

Check image below for better explanation.
[image]